# Search for other iOS-devices with Framework(in app) running?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

Is there an Objective-C-Framework, with which I can search for other ios-devices which are also running this framework?

For example, something like that:

- A starts the app.
- B starts the app also.
- The apps now search for nearby running devices with this specific app.

I don't want to solve this with a server. The device should handle it itself.
Also the Framework should offer a possibility to send strings, or data between these devices.

So the "iBeacon-Framework" doesn't work for me.

Comment: `Multipeer Connectivity` framework?

Answer (score 0):

The ibeacon protocol alone won't do the job (of sending strings), but you'll fall under either Bluetooth or Wifi connectivity to achieve what you want to. Using any of these, you can easily come up with a way to detect the sister app.

A possibly smart solution would be: iBeacon to detect the other device and initiate normal  Bluetooth data transfer.